Cannot display a decoded video frame on Raylib
I'm trying to explore libav and raylib just to understand how audio and video work, and also to learn how to build nice interfaces using the raylib project. I've implemented a simple struct capable of decoding audio and video frames. When a video frame appears, I convert it to the RGBA format, which packs the values into 32bpp. This is the setup:
    if (av_image_alloc((uint8_t **)media->dst_frame->data,
                       media->dst_frame->linesize, media->ctxs[0]->width,
                       media->ctxs[0]->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA, 1) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to setup dest image\n");
        return -1;
    }

    media->sws_ctx = sws_getContext(
        media->ctxs[0]->width, media->ctxs[0]->height, media->ctxs[0]->pix_fmt,
        media->ctxs[0]->width, media->ctxs[0]->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
        SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, 0);

    // Later on, in the decode function:
    int ret = sws_scale(media->sws_ctx, media->frame->data,
                            media->frame->linesize, 0, media->frame->height,
                            media->dst_frame->data, media->dst_frame->linesize);


In the main file, I init raylib, and setup the necessary steps to load the texture (here I'm trying to fetch the first video frame in order to show the user a preview of the video, later on I plan to reset the stream to allow a correct playback routine). I think the format of the image is right.
    Image previewImage =
        GenImageColor(videoArea.width, videoArea.height, BLACK);
    // I assume this makes the formats compatible
    ImageFormat(&previewImage, PIXELFORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED_R8G8B8A8);

    Texture2D videoTexture = LoadTextureFromImage(previewImage);
    UnloadImage(previewImage);


        if (!state->has_media) {
            DrawText("Drop a video file here!", videoArea.x + 10,
                     videoArea.y + 10, 20, GRAY);
        } else {
            if (state->first_frame) {
                do {
                    decode_packet(state->media);
                } while (!is_frame_video(state->media));

                UpdateTexture(videoTexture, state->media->dst_frame->data[0]);

                state->first_frame = 0;
            }
        }

        DrawTexture(videoTexture, videoArea.x, videoArea.y, WHITE);

Anyway, this is what I get when a mp4 file is dropped:

It seems like an alignment issue maybe? Can someone point me in the right direction in order to correctly solve this problem?
